# Vite build runs with error while dev runs fine, and IDE did not complain (Vue3, Typescript)

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, vite

I have this custom component code

```
 <SideNavItem    
    :sideNavItemData="new SideNavItemData({
        itemName: SideNavItemName.Home,
    })"
></SideNavItem>
```

with SideNavItemName being a enum

```
export enum SideNavItemName {
    Home = 'home',
    Race = 'race',
    Report = 'data',
    Qa = 'qa',
    Payment = 'payment',
    Faq = 'faq',
}
```

and the code was seemingly minimized to

```
ge(fE,{sideNavItemData:new y(rA)({itemName:y(Ep).Home})}
```

When I run the build in browser, this results in a `TypeError: class constructors must be invoked with 'new'`.

I've tried to build with --target=ES6 or --target=ES2020 with no avail. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const homeItem = ref<SideNavItemData>(new SideNavItemData({
    itemName: SideNavItemName.Home,
}));
```

Moving the item to a ref solved the problem. Still don't know why thought.